# Need to convert PHP Regex into JavaScript regex

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need to convert this PHP flavoured Regex:

```
(?<=\A|\;#)(.*?)(?=\;#|\z)
```

Into Javascript flavoured Regex.

I keep on getting unidentified token error while using the existing PHP version in my code.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Javascript does not support lookbehinds, I think you may be better off explaining what you are trying to match with some example content

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds, nor are `\A` and `\z` anchors.

You don't really even need a lookarounds in that regex. You could just use a non-capturing group, and then access the first capture group. Use `^` instead of `\A`, and `$` instead of `\z`. You also don't need to escape the `;`.

```regex
(?:^|;#)(.*?)(?:;#|$)
```

And then use the value in the first capture group.